# Generating a compiled application from an Apple Script

Tags: macos, applescript

For an application uninstaller I use an Apple Script that I save in Apple Script Editor to a .app bundle. What I would like to do is to generate that .app bundle from the command line (so I can incorporate the step into an automated build script, and not have the bundle in a repo). Is this possible ? I have yet to find a command line interface to Apple Script Editor...

Edit: Just found osacompile... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the man page for the `osacompile` command.

Comment: Thanks Ned, found the osacompile command, now I just need to get it work in my build script :)